# How to export connections in Robo 3T (Robomongo)

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

Is the any better way to share connection settings from `Robo 3T` by avoiding just copy-pasting of each connection details?

I didn't find anything in menu of `Robo 3T`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I didn't find the way to do it from `Robo 3T`. Maybe one day we will get [this feature](https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues/623).

But you can copy the entire `robo3t.json` configuration file, that contains all details.

It is not the best solution, because you will need to update connection settings with passwords(they are empty) and path to Private key (if path is different from machine where you copied your setting file), but it will make this process easier.

One more detail, I use Linux and installed `Robo 3T` via `snap`, so here the list of possible places of `robo3t.json` configuration file ([more details](https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/wiki/Robomongo-Config-File-Guide)):

[image]

Please pay attention, that '.3T' folder is a hidden folder.

Linux

```
1.3 
/home/snap/robo3t-snap/4/.3T/robo-3t/1.3.1

1.1
/home/<user>/.3T/robo-3t/1.1.1/robo3t.json

1.0
/home/<user>/.3T/robomongo/1.0.0/robomongo.json

1.0-RC1
/home/<user>/.config/robomongo/1.0/robomongo.json

0.9.x
/home/<user>/.config/robomongo/0.9/robomongo.json

0.8.x
/home/<user>/.config/robomongo/robomongo.json
```

Windows

```
1.1
C:\Users\<user>\.3T\robo-3t\1.1.1\robo3t.json

1.0
C:\Users\<user>\.3T\robomongo\1.0.0\robomongo.json

1.0-RC1
C:\Users\<user>\.config\robomongo\1.0\robomongo.json

0.9.x
C:\Users\<user>\.config\robomongo\0.9\robomongo.json

0.8.x
C:\Users\<user>\.config\robomongo\robomongo.json
```

MAC

```
1.1
/Users/<user>/.3T/robo-3t/1.1.1/robo3t.json

1.0
/Users/<user>/.3T/robomongo/1.0.0/robomongo.json

1.0-RC1
/Users/<user>/.config/robomongo/1.0/robomongo.json

0.9.x
/Users/<user>/.config/robomongo/0.9/robomongo.json

0.8.x
/Users/<user>/.config/robomongo/robomongo.json
```

Comment: @Kane could you provide some details? what version do you install? what is your OS?

Comment: @Kane I've added details to answer. Possibly check  that '.3T' folder is a hidden folder.